# Why is module not found only when doing unit testing with pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-cov

I'm having a problem running unit tests. I have a project structure like this:

Given this directory

```
who-said-what/
    |
    |_ wave_encoder.py
    | 
    |_ tests/
        |_ test_wave_encoder.py
```

where `test_wave_encoder.py` looks like this:

```
from wave_encoder import *

class TestEncoder():
    def test_plot_no_fit1(self):
        encoder = WaveEncoder()
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, encoder.plot_signal)

    def test_plot_no_fit2(self):
        encoder = WaveEncoder()
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, encoder.plot_transform)

    def test_plot_no_fit3(self):
        encoder = WaveEncoder()
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, encoder.plot_components)
```

If I run this test file individually, no issues. However, if I try to run pytest from any directory in the project:

```
pytest -v --cov ./tests 
# or
pytest -v --cov .
```

I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wave_encoder'`.

However, if I move `test_wave_encoder.py` to the parent directory, it does work (there are other errors, but that's a different question).

I don't really want a bunch of test files in the parent directory. How do I sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: place an empty `conftest.py` in your root.
Step 2: run tests from root folder with `python -m pytest`

That should work.

Comment: Okay, that did indeed work. Why is this method required as apposed to what I did, which came from a RealPython tutorial I just watched? Just trying to learn. And further, will this method be compatible with CircleCI (also something I'm learning on RealPython)

Comment: To be honest, I just ran into the same problem today and that is how I figured:p the first step tells purest what the root is (and thus, where tests and actual code is). This is used as pythonpath within pytest. The second step is a windows with virtual environment thing. I noticed that pytest would run against my global Python rather then my intended virtual env Python if I just called `pytest`. When I am in an activated env, pytest must be run in that env. Please accept the answer if it fixed your issue:) kudos are always welcome

Comment: I can't accept for another 3 minutes, but I will.